# TSQL: Incorrect syntax near function name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this one: (updated)

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.fn_getProductCatPurchased', N'IF') IS NOT NULL
DROP FUNCTION [dbo].fn_getProductCatPurchased;
GO
```

then the function starts:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].fn_getProductCatPurchased
(
@Custno varchar(100), 
@PriceType varchar(100)
)

RETURNS int 
AS 

BEGIN
    DECLARE @groups int;
    SELECT @groups = COUNT(DISTINCT(prodcat)) 
    FROM SALES 
    WHERE custno = @Custno 
        AND pricetype=@PriceType
     IF (@group IS NULL) 
        SET @group = 0;
    RETURN @group;
  END;
  GO
```

When I try to save the function an error was thrown:

```
Incorrect syntax near fn_getProductCatPurchased
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is something else which produces this error, the code you supplied on its own does exactly what it should when i executed it. Please supply more info about what you are doing.

Comment: Are you doing this from SQL Server Management Studio or elsewhere? `GO` is not T-SQL.

Comment: I have updated the code now. If I remove GO - it;s the same :)

Comment: To me it compiled successfully.

Comment: I'll try another client then. thanks!

Comment: You are trying to drop an inline table function and your function does not return a table. Try with FN OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.fn_getProductCatPurchased', N'FN') IS NOT NULL

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the cause of your error, but it's definitely a problem.

You are declaring a variable called `@groups`:

```
DECLARE @groups int;
```

but proceed to use `@group` without an `s` instead:

```
IF (@group IS NULL) 
    SET @group = 0;
RETURN @group;
```